# Is there a way to indent with spaces, similary as you can indent with tabs

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse I can select some text and then press tab to indent it, and shift-tab to remove a single tab indent.

Is there a similar way to do the same thing, but with spaces instead of tabs?

I am not trying to replace space with tabs in general, and I still want to indent all my code with tabs. But sometimes I have non code text which need a space indent.

It's mostly in the text editor, but it would also be nice if the solution worked in other editors.

Comment: You can set Eclipse to use spaces rather than tabs for everything, but that is all.

Comment: There is a general setting for text-based editors and there are specific settings for Java, XML, etc. which can override the general setting.